# unity scripts location after build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

hello i wanted to know where are unity scripts stored in a build...

actually i want to give update to my game but saw that there's no proper way to do it without giving full update... assetbundles cant import executable code... so what i came up with is make an entire new application/unity project which acts like a launcher to my game and it will fetch a json from server with all filenames and latest versions and compare them to the filenames and versions on disk... then it downloads and replaces any missing or old version files from the disk with streamwriter and all... then it will call to start the actual game's exe and quit itself...

Now what the problem is that i dont know where are scripts(the custom scripts we made during development) are compiled and stored to as dll or any other files so i can look out for them because i noticed there are a lot of system(default) dll in unity build and i dont want to iterate through them every time my application checks for an update...

**Edit:**

it strike me sometime after... i also wanted to know if all of our scripts are compiled(and stored in a build) in one dll or whatever file or as separate dlls. cuz say if i have scripts almost extending to 50mb and if i give even a minor update, downloading the whole 50mb dll wont be worth for the update mechanism the way i vision it to be...

**Please ignore my grammar. english is my second language**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Unity compiles everything game related into the assembly: Assembly-CSharp.dll

All the assemblies are located in /GAME NAME_Data/Managed/

You can however split your code up into different assemblies using [Assembly Definitions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html).

Comment: thanks for the help... i dont exactly get the assembly definitions from documentation but i will get it eventually... thanks again